# In android, is it possible to create a notification when another app is opened?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'd like to know if it is possible to create a notification or toast/alert from my app when another app is opened. For example, my app Foo will create a notification if Facebook is opened.

Edit: What I actually want is to inform the user that my app is running in the background when the default camera app opens/running. My app will modify photos taken with the default camera app when it is running in the background and I want to inform the user that it will do so. Is this possible?

Comment: You are never notified if the ActivityStack changes so you'll never know if another application is opened. This is a question of a privacy concern. The question is why should you 'some app' know why or when my app launched?

Comment: @JoxTraex That's false, you can get a list of active applications.

Comment: as I said, you cannot get WHEN it changes, I never said you can't query a list of applications. Also the API you're referring is discouraged : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses() .

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want is a push notification. Please go through following tuts to help yourself:

https://neurobin.org/docs/android/push-notification-gcm-client-server/

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, you can take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) and then schedule an alarm using some background running process that looks for Facebook being running.

One way is to use AlarmManager to check running apps every 5-10 mins and you can generate a notification if your condition is met.

Comment: Why was this voted down? It's an acceptable way to check currently running apps/processes....